# Broadcastreceived in Activity

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

In my service I have a SendBroadCast () that sends my intent with the information I need (for update listview in activity). But how can I retrieve this information from the Activity? If I create an extended class for BroadcastReceiver I can retrieve this information, but how to do the activity?

My service:

```
            Intent myIn = new Intent(this, typeof(MyActivity));

            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

            bundle.PutString("value1", "value_1");

            bundle.PutString("value2", "value_2");

            myIn.PutExtra("myaction",bundle);

            SendBroadcast(myIn);
```

Comment: you are asking how to get this sending data in your next activity right ?

Comment: @Darkie after sending data by sendbroadcast i need to recover these values in the activity and update the listview

Answer (score 0):

```
u can send like this,


 Intent myIn = new Intent(this, typeof(MyActivity));

         //instead of bundle use like this 

            myIn.PutExtra("value1", "value_1");

            myIn.PutExtra("value2", "value_2");

          SendBroadcast(myIn);


and get them on activity like,


      private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            String value1 = intent.getStringExtra("value1");
      String value2 = intent.getStringExtra("value2");


        }

    };
```

Answer (score 0):

you get data in your next activity like this ...

```
String  abc, Last;
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
Last = extras.getString("value1");
abc = extras.getString("value2");
```